# VLC and WPF : Viewing Panel eats up all other controls on screen?

Tags: wpf, vlc

Good morning,

I don’t have a problem getting vlc working in wpf but it seems that the viewing panel
(which is a WinForm panel wrapped in WindowsFormsHost) eats up all the controls on top. Everything looks fine until I run it and my buttons will disappear because the panel is covering them. is this a VLC settings or is it wpf settings ?

Any ideas? Thanks - Sam E

Answer (score 0):

This is a commonly known issue in WPF when dealing with Interop controls. It's known as the [airspace issue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970688.aspx). Basically, WPF content cannot render on top of any WinForms/etc Interop controls.